# Extract capybara element/object from Selenium element

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I had to identify few web elements in  a page through its class value or name value. But as the `Capybara::Node::Finders#find` supports only css and xpath as locator I did this(Converted Capybara element to Selenium element):

```
element = page.driver.browser.find_element(:class,locatorValue)
```

Now i'm able to fetch the element with class value as *I'm using Selenium element underneath*. But this compells me to use only webdriver apis and not capybara apis

For eg: I have to go for `element.send_keys 'input'` instead of `element.set 'input'` or `element.fill_in 'input'`

**Is there any way I can get back a Capybara element from Selenium element?? The reverse of what I have done in getting Selenium object earlier??**

Comment: Why would you not want to just write a CSS (or XPath) selector and use the Capybara API? For example, you could do `element = page.find(".#{locatorValue}")`, assuming `locatorValue` is a class name.

Comment: Yes I know that would be the simplest way of doing it. I tried it too, like get the class name n build the xpath myself. But if I wanna get the element using some other attribute like 'name' or 'text' as I could do using watir-webdriver, I'd need a solution like i asked. Just trying to find something here :)

Comment: Each of those properties can be found using CSS selectors and/or Xpath. For the most part that is what Watir-Webdriver does under the covers.

Comment: Yes.. Got it :) I'm doing the same now. Build css string with ".#{classname}" and "##{idvalue}".
Thank You :)

Comment: I know this is an old thread, I just got to the same problem. The issue for me is that `Each of those properties can be found using CSS selectors` is not true when working with shadow doms